# PIL ImageGrab fails on 2nd virtual monitor of VirtualBox

Tags: python, image, screenshot, python-imaging-library, virtualbox

I set up a VirtualBox to use two monitors. I tried taking a screenshot of a window on the second monitor:

```
import ImageGrab
im = ImageGrab.grab(windowrect)
im.save("img.png")
```

`windowrect` I verified to be the correct rect of the window, in this case, `(1616, 2, 2594, 732)`. However, `img.png` is just a big black box. Any ideas how to fix this interaction between screen grabbing and VirtualBox so that I can take screenshots of the 2nd virtual monitor?

Comment: i've noticed that `gtk` can do this, as well as a native win32 approach [here](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/576924-win32ui-vs-wxpy-screen-capture-multi-monitor)

Answer (score 2):

I've faced this same issue. If I had to guess, I'd assume that `ImageGrab` is getting its coordinates from the SM_SCREEN flag, which gives the coordinates of the primary monitor only, rather than the SM_VIRTUALSCREEN, which gives the entire virtual screen (I haven't looked through the source though, so just a guess).

That said, it's easy enough to get around this by interacting directly with the Windows API, then converting its bitmap output into a more usable PIL object.

#### Some Code:

```
def _get_screen_buffer(self, bounds=None):
                # Grabs a DC to the entire virtual screen, but only copies to 
                # the bitmap the the rect defined by the user. 

                SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN = 76  # coordinates for the left side of the virtual screen. 
                SM_YVIRTUALSCREEN = 77  # coordinates for the right side of the virtual screen.  
                SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN = 78 # width of the virtual screen
                SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN = 79 # height of the virtual screen

                hDesktopWnd = windll.user32.GetDesktopWindow() #Entire virtual Screen

                left = windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN)
                top = windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(SM_YVIRTUALSCREEN)
                width = windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN)
                height = windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN)

                if bounds:
                        left, top, right, bottom = bounds
                        width = right - left 
                        height = bottom - top
                
                hDesktopDC = windll.user32.GetWindowDC(hDesktopWnd)
                if not hDesktopDC: print 'GetDC Failed'; sys.exit()
                
                hCaptureDC = windll.gdi32.CreateCompatibleDC(hDesktopDC)
                if not hCaptureDC: print 'CreateCompatibleBitmap Failed'; sys.exit()

                hCaptureBitmap = windll.gdi32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDesktopDC, width, height)
                if not hCaptureBitmap: print 'CreateCompatibleBitmap Failed'; sys.exit()
                
                windll.gdi32.SelectObject(hCaptureDC, hCaptureBitmap)

                SRCCOPY = 0x00CC0020
                windll.gdi32.BitBlt(
                        hCaptureDC, 
                        0, 0, 
                        width, height, 
                        hDesktopDC, 
                        left, top, 
                        0x00CC0020
                )
                return hCaptureBitmap

        def _make_image_from_buffer(self, hCaptureBitmap):
                import Image
                bmp_info = BITMAPINFO()
                bmp_header = BITMAPFILEHEADER()
                hdc = windll.user32.GetDC(None)

                bmp_info.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)

                DIB_RGB_COLORS = 0
                windll.gdi32.GetDIBits(hdc, 
                        hCaptureBitmap, 
                        0,0, 
                        None, byref(bmp_info), 
                        DIB_RGB_COLORS
                )

                bmp_info.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = bmp_info.bmiHeader.biWidth *abs(bmp_info.bmiHeader.biHeight) * (bmp_info.bmiHeader.biBitCount+7)/8;
                size = (bmp_info.bmiHeader.biWidth, bmp_info.bmiHeader.biHeight )
                print size
                pBuf = (c_char * bmp_info.bmiHeader.biSizeImage)()

                windll.gdi32.GetBitmapBits(hCaptureBitmap, bmp_info.bmiHeader.biSizeImage, pBuf)

                return Image.frombuffer('RGB', size, pBuf, 'raw', 'BGRX', 0, 1)
```

The first function gets a bitmap of the screen, and the second guy converts it to a PIL object.

If you don't want to figure out the coordinates of the other monitors yourself, I've got a small module called [PyRobot](https://github.com/chriskiehl/pyrobot) which has functions for targeting specific monitors and whatnot. And it's pure Python, so no need to install PyWin32 :)

Answer (score 0):

Audionautics / chriskiehl !

I took your post and some of your library and re-write it for python 3 ! I hope you're okay with it. It works for me using PILLOW (PIL) and the python 3.4 engine.

**I just called the file duelMonitory.py containing**:

```
# https://github.com/chriskiehl/pyrobot
# started from Audionautics code on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585293/pil-imagegrab-fails-on-2nd-virtual-monitor-of-virtualbox
# updated for PILLOW and Python 3 by Alan Baines (Kizrak)


from PIL import *
#from ctypes import windll, Structure, byref, c_uint
#import ctypes

import ctypes
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import *

def get_screen_buffer(bounds=None):
    # Grabs a DC to the entire virtual screen, but only copies to 
    # the bitmap the the rect defined by the user. 

    SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN = 76  # coordinates for the left side of the virtual screen. 
    SM_YVIRTUALSCREEN = 77  # coordinates for the right side of the virtual screen.  
    SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN = 78 # width of the virtual screen
    SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN = 79 # height of the virtual screen

    hDesktopWnd = windll.user32.GetDesktopWindow() #Entire virtual Screen

    left = windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN)
    top = windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(SM_YVIRTUALSCREEN)
    width = windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN)
    height = windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN)

    if bounds:
        left, top, right, bottom = bounds
        width = right - left 
        height = bottom - top

    hDesktopDC = windll.user32.GetWindowDC(hDesktopWnd)
    if not hDesktopDC:
        print ('GetDC Failed')
        sys.exit()

    hCaptureDC = windll.gdi32.CreateCompatibleDC(hDesktopDC)
    if not hCaptureDC:
        print ('CreateCompatibleBitmap Failed')
        sys.exit()

    hCaptureBitmap = windll.gdi32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDesktopDC, width, height)
    if not hCaptureBitmap:
        print ('CreateCompatibleBitmap Failed')
        sys.exit()

    windll.gdi32.SelectObject(hCaptureDC, hCaptureBitmap)

    SRCCOPY = 0x00CC0020
    windll.gdi32.BitBlt(
        hCaptureDC, 
        0, 0, 
        width, height, 
        hDesktopDC, 
        left, top, 
        0x00CC0020
    )
    return hCaptureBitmap

def make_image_from_buffer(hCaptureBitmap):
    from PIL import Image
    bmp_info = BITMAPINFO()
    bmp_header = BITMAPFILEHEADER()
    hdc = windll.user32.GetDC(None)

    bmp_info.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)

    DIB_RGB_COLORS = 0
    windll.gdi32.GetDIBits(hdc, 
        hCaptureBitmap, 
        0,0, 
        None, byref(bmp_info), 
        DIB_RGB_COLORS
    )

    bmp_info.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = int( bmp_info.bmiHeader.biWidth *abs(bmp_info.bmiHeader.biHeight) * (bmp_info.bmiHeader.biBitCount+7)/8 );
    size = (bmp_info.bmiHeader.biWidth, bmp_info.bmiHeader.biHeight )
    print (size)
    pBuf = (c_char * bmp_info.bmiHeader.biSizeImage)()

    windll.gdi32.GetBitmapBits(hCaptureBitmap, bmp_info.bmiHeader.biSizeImage, pBuf)

    return Image.frombuffer('RGB', size, pBuf, 'raw', 'BGRX', 0, 1)


class BITMAPFILEHEADER(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('bfType', ctypes.c_short),
        ('bfSize', ctypes.c_uint32),
        ('bfReserved1', ctypes.c_short),
        ('bfReserved2', ctypes.c_short),
        ('bfOffBits', ctypes.c_uint32)
    ]


class BITMAPINFOHEADER(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('biSize', ctypes.c_uint32),
        ('biWidth', ctypes.c_int),
        ('biHeight', ctypes.c_int),
        ('biPlanes', ctypes.c_short),
        ('biBitCount', ctypes.c_short),
        ('biCompression', ctypes.c_uint32),
        ('biSizeImage', ctypes.c_uint32),
        ('biXPelsPerMeter', ctypes.c_long),
        ('biYPelsPerMeter', ctypes.c_long),
        ('biClrUsed', ctypes.c_uint32),
        ('biClrImportant', ctypes.c_uint32)
    ]


class BITMAPINFO(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('bmiHeader', BITMAPINFOHEADER),
        ('bmiColors', ctypes.c_ulong * 3)
    ]
```

**And my test code was duelMonitor.test.py containing**:

```
from PIL import *

from duelMonitor import *

hCaptureBitmap = get_screen_buffer()

pimage = make_image_from_buffer(hCaptureBitmap)

pimage.save("Hello.png","PNG")
```

Basically just combination of Audionautics post and his library from https://github.com/chriskiehl/pyrobot webpage and conversion to Python 3 (and PILLOW).

Have fun!

(PS. I would have posted as comment, but I don't have enough points /sadface)

Answer (score 0):

```
imageGrab.grab(bbox = (x1,y1,x2,y2), all_screens=True)
```

should help. Otherwise the second display area is blank